# Misaligned DetailsView controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I'm using a DetailsView in an applicaoon I am developing, and have a minor issue. My detailsview has multiple control types - checkboxs, textboxs, drop down lists etc. They are all *slightly* misaligned from each other vertically -I.e. Text boss are pushed slightly right for some reason.

I can easily fix it by changing the margins of the controls so they line up, but that's rather 'hacky' and probably won't work well in all browsers. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did you find out why they're misaligned? That might help you in finding the most effective solution. Are you familiar with the IE Developer Tools (F12 in IE) or Chrome's "Inspect Element" (right-click on a control and choose Inspect Element)? Those are great tools for checking alignment, CSS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the align of detailsview so every item will be have the same align.